# Error log count and Error log Messages as list from Logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, error-logging, python-logging

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.error("first error")

data = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    a = data + 10
except:
    logger.error('except error')
logger.error('end of script')
```

what is the best possible way to get how many times Error log is called in the script? and there is any way i can get all error log messages from logger as a list ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom `logging.handler`

```
class CustomStreamHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_logs = []

    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            self.error_logs.append(record)
        super().emit(record)

handler = CustomStreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.error("first error")
print(handler.error_logs)
```